# what is __dirstream, where can we find the definition

Tags: c, linux, header, directory, posix

As we can see in `dirent.h`, there is a typedef:

```
typedef struct __dirstream DIR;
```

It says it's opaque to users. And we can't find it even in gcc headers, the `__dirstream` structure definition can only be found in glibc source code. I am wondering why this structure has to be opaque (I don't think it's plausible to say it prevents user from direct reference, probably I am wrong)? What's the catch?

Comment: It's opaque so that users of the library can't poke around random values in it.

Comment: @H2CO3 But if you really want to, you can just copy the definition in glibc to your program, it doesn't prevent anything actually. And I don't think it's a good idea to conceal the structure with intention to prevent random modification, I think informing the user on manual is enough.

Comment: You can, of course nothing can be prevented, but most users can't even google where the source code of glibc is :P In programming, nothing is impossible, and this isn't implemented like so because the Earth explodes if you do this, this is just **that** small piece of security barrier that will prevent monkeys with guns in there handz from messing around with internal structures.

Answer (score 7):

You can find the actual definition [here](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/dirstream.h;h=8303f07fab6f6efaa39e51411ef924e712d995e0;hb=fa39685d5c7df2502213418bead44e9543a9b9ec), but as has been pointed out you're not supposed to access it directly.

It can change randomly between implementations of the standard library (or different releases of the same library) which is why it's hidden.

Your comment about "informing the user" being enough is a bit ... I don't know, it's a very optimistic outlook. Hiding the definition makes it harder to abuse it, which in turn makes it harder to write programs that violate the specification and contain pointlessly brittle code. It's a good thing; you'll find a lot of software engineering is dedicated to trying to prevent programmers from doing what they're not supposed to be doing.

This in turn is not necessarily because "all programmers are stupid", at least that's not my interpretation, it's rather since the complexity of typical software systems is very, very high, it becomes beneficial to try to reduce it whenever possible. Information hiding is one way of reducing the complexity at one particular place in the system.

Comment: Yes, I understand what you are saying, IMHO, it's like oo programming. I just suspect there might be some other reason... But if it's the cause, I can comprehend this.

Comment: @dspjm I had the same question as you (I was just curious about its structure and had no real reason to need to know) and I had an important realization: if you're not expert enough to find the definition of the struct, you're not expert enough to be using it. :)