# Linux sizeof struct @ runtime?

Tags: c, linux

[what is __dirstream, where can we find the definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893895/what-is-dirstream-where-can-we-find-the-definition)

So, I'm trying to get the sizeof DIR from opendir, which is a typedef of __dirstream. I understand it's hidden at compile-time, is there a defined max size?

Comment: Why do you need the size?

Comment: I'm writing a remote FUSE file system, and I need to get the structure to send it, and preferably transform it to be cross-architecture (ie 32-bit/64-bit) @CholNhial

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `__` double-underscore in the name marks it as implementation-private. Nothing is defined about it except what the implementation documents.

> is there a defined max size

Nope, sorry.

Comment: So if I need to copy it to another location in memory, there is NO way to do it?

Comment: Exactly. You should think about the design of your application and find another way.